# Generator + Promise combination; control flow explanation

Tags: node.js, promise, generator, event-loop

Using some code found at https://www.promisejs.org/generators/, I've put together this test script (probably not relevant but I am running it by executing `regenerator --include-runtime gentest.js > gentest-out.js && node gentest-out.js`):

```
function async(makeGenerator){
  return function () {
    var generator = makeGenerator.apply(this, arguments);

    function handle(result){
      // result => { done: [Boolean], value: [Object] }
      console.log('  entered handle, result:', result);
      if (result.done) {
          console.log('  done, returning result.value:', result.value);
          return Promise.resolve(result.value);
      }

      console.log('  not done yet, returning promise');
      return Promise.resolve(result.value).then(function (res){
          console.log('    inside then.. res is', res);
          var me = generator.next(res);
          console.log('    generator.next(' + res + ') =', me);
        return handle(me);
      }, function (err){
        return handle(generator.throw(err));
      });
    }

    try {
      return handle(generator.next());
    } catch (ex) {
      return Promise.reject(ex);
    }
  }
}

var get = async(function*() {
    var left = new Promise(function(resolve,reject) {
        console.log('in promise object');
        setTimeout(function() {
            console.log('  in promise timeout function');
            setTimeout(function() {
                console.log('    in second timeout function');
                resolve(1)
            }, 10000);
        }, 3000)
    });
    console.log('got to before right=5');
    var right = 5;
    console.log('yield left:', yield left);
    console.log('got to after yield left');
    console.log('yield right:', yield right);
    console.log('returning');
    return 
});

console.log('get is instance of Promise before call:', get instanceof Promise)
console.log('get is instance of promise once called:', get() instanceof Promise);
```

The result is:

```
get is instance of Promise before call: false
in promise object
got to before right=5
  entered handle, result: { value: {}, done: false }
  not done yet, returning promise
get is instance of promise once called: true
  <long pause here>
  in promise timeout function 
    <longer pause here>
    in second timeout function 
    inside then.. res is 1
yield left: 1
got to after yield left
    generator.next(1) = { value: 5, done: false }
  entered handle, result: { value: 5, done: false }
  not done yet, returning promise
    inside then.. res is 5
yield right: 5
returning
    generator.next(5) = { value: undefined, done: true }
  entered handle, result: { value: undefined, done: true }
  done, returning result.value: undefined
```

My questions are:

1. Why is the `result.value` of the initial `generator.next()` call equal
   to `{}`? Shouldn't it be the Promise object assigned to left?
2. It seems that the `Promise.resolve(result.value)` inside of the handle
   function is blocking. I expected the promise to be returned while
   the .then method runs on the next tick. Instead it seems that
   `Promise.resolve` does not lose control until the .then method's
   callback executes a `resolve(1)`. Is that what is happening here? **Edit** - I'm thinking .then does execute on the next tick but there's nothing else in the event loop, so it looks blocking.. but it still doesn't explain why the Promise object is not returned immediately.

Comment: You might want to seperate this to two different questions, and include the relevant parts in each one.

Comment: Agreed - both the code and console output could be distilled.